# Sqlite - Unable to return selected data angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

In my ionic app. I created a service named **webservice** to retrieve data from sqlite database using angularjs.It selecting data properly and get result in console it works fine, but it return **undefined** always.

**This is my sample code:**

```
app.factory('webservice',function($http,$cordovaSQLite,$q){

    var obj = {};

    obj.getNote =  function(){
        var query = "SELECT subject, note FROM notes";
        var q = $q.defer();
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
            if(res.rows.length > 0) {               
                var data = res.rows;
                console.log(data); //Result - Working..
                q.resolve(res.rows); //Result - Undefined..
                return data; //Result - Undefined..
            } else {
                console.log("No results found");
                return false;
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

    return obj;

});
```

**This is my controller:**

```
app.controller('noteCtrl', function($scope,$state,webservice){

    $scope.getNote =  function(){
        console.log(webservice.getNote()); // Undefined.
    }

});
```

So please try to find out good solution for me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things. First you're not returning the promise object from your service, second, you are not calling the then function within the controller. Try the following code:

```
app.factory('webservice',function($http,$cordovaSQLite,$q){

    var obj = {};

    obj.getNote =  function(){
        var query = "SELECT subject, note FROM notes";
        var q = $q.defer(); //this is your deferred object
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
            if(res.rows.length > 0) {               
                var data = res.rows;
                console.log(data); //Result - Working..
                q.resolve(res.rows); //Result - Undefined..
                return data; //Result - Undefined..
            } else {
                console.log("No results found");
                q.reject("No results found"); 
                return false;
            }
        }, function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
            console.error(err);
        });

        return q.promise;       //This line was missing

    }

    return obj;

});
```

and in controller do this :

```
 app.controller('noteCtrl', function($scope,$state,webservice){

    $scope.getNote =  function(){
        webservice.getNote().then(
            function(res){   //success callback
             console.log(res);  //this should be the resolved object
            },
            function(err){   //error callback
             console.log(err);  //this should be the rejected object
            });
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But when i use ng-repeat in view i get the below error `[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` Could your tell me How to fix this?